# Error al crear un cliente socket en c++

Tags: c++, socket

Tengo un programa que al momento de la ejecución, se queda en medio proceso y se detiene sin mostrar ningún mensaje de error al crear una conexión socket, es raro porque tengo un ejemplo que si funciona bien, la única diferencia es que este lo hice orientado a objetos, creando la clase cliente y retornando la conexión creada.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws_32")

class client{
    private:
        int port;
        struct hostent *host;
    public:
        client(char* _host, int _port);
        SOCKET init();
        ~client();
};

// params config socket
client::client(char* _host, int _port = 4444){
    host = gethostbyname(_host);
    port = _port;
}

// return socket
SOCKET client::init(){
    try{
        WSADATA wsaData;
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) != 0) {
            std::cout << " ws failed..." << std::endl;
            throw std::string("WSAStartup failed");
        }
        std::cout << "paso 1..." << std::endl;
        SOCKADDR_IN sockAddr;
        sockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
        sockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

        std::cout << "paso 2..." << std::endl;
        SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&sockAddr),sizeof(sockAddr)) != 0){ 
            std::cout << "socket failed..." << std::endl;
            throw std::string("Socket conection failed");
        }
        std::cout << "paso 3..." << std::endl;
        return Socket;
    }catch(std::string e){
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }catch(std::exception& e){
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

client::~client(){
    std::string("destruido");
}
```

en el main retorno la clase creada y la realizo una pedicion a una pagina pasando los parametros al iniciar el programa

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

// class {
#include "client.cpp"
// }

int main(int args, char* argc[]){
    // try{
        if(args <= 1){
            throw std::string("params required");
        }
        // params
        // std::cout << "host:" << argc[1] << std::endl;
        // std::cout << "port:" << argc[2] << std::endl;
        
        client sock(argc[1], atoi( argc[2]));
        std::cout << "iniciando conexion..." << std::endl;
        SOCKET cliente = sock.init();
        std::cout << "socket creado..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << cliente << std::endl;

        send(cliente,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"),0); 
        char buffer[10000]; 
        int nDataLength;

        while ((nDataLength = recv(cliente,buffer,10000,0)) > 0){ 
            int i = 0; 
            while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') { 
                std::cout << buffer[i]; 
                i += 1; 
            } 
        }

        closesocket(cliente); 
        WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se resolvió quitando los try/catch de la función de creación del socket, ya pude ver el error y corregirlo.